Autowire a service class and create a new object of the same service class
If I Autowire a service class and create a new object of the same service class again by new Service(). How many service object will get created?
When I am using setter injection to create a new object will that object will create when the class loads or it will created whenever required?
I want to clarify my concept of object creation in Spring boot using various ways

Spring supports multiple bean scopes. 
Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/factory-scopes.html 
Default is singleton, Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance for each Spring IoC container.
@Bean
ServiceA mybean(){
return new ServiceA();
}

@Service
class ServiceA{
}

@Service
class ServiceC{


//same bean is injected 
@Autowired
ServiceA serviceA;


void processing(){
System.out.println("my object hascode is " + serviceA.hascode())
serviceA.send();


}

@Service
class ServiceB{

//This is new object not what is created by Spring above - will have different  hashcode - howver since ServiceB is singleton - only one instance of this service will be used. 
final ServiceA serviceA = new ServiceA();

void processing(){
System.out.println("my object hascode is " + serviceA.hascode())
serviceA.send();

}

}


Following block of code in spring application doesn't have to do anything to spring scope. 

void processing(){
service = new ServiceA();
service.send();

}

